# Sending SMS with AT command through C#

Tags: c#, sms

I have written SMS application in C#. My question is:I want to send SMS to multiple users. But,it's sending to one user. What is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public void openPort()
    {
        port.Close();
        port.PortName = "COM11";
        port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
        port.BaudRate = 115200;
        port.DtrEnable = true;
        port.Open();
     }
  public void sendSMS(string mmobil)
  {
       this.mobil = mmobil;
       port.WriteLine("AT\r");
        port.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1\r");
        port.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + mmobil + "\"\r");
        port.WriteLine("TEST" + '\x001a');
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
    {


 List <string>mymobil= new List<string>();
        mymobil.Add("+316207XXX");
        mymobil.Add("+316141XXX");

 foreach (string mobil in mymobil)
       {

           openPort();
           sendSMS(mobil);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read device user manual first, I think there should be a delay after you send your first sms maybe device returns something you have to read it to clear the buffer, then send again. It's completely depend on what device you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using third party SMPP providers, then you have to ask them to allow to send multi users, else use ";" each number.

thank you

Comment: I think all providers let users to send multiple sms, it's more likely to chose many contact in your mobile phone to send sms to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not sending the escape character needed after the text message. you should send ASCII character ESC which is 27 in decimal and 1B in Hexadecimal.